# Can not convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'const wchar_t *' + windows phone runtime component

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, c++-cli, c++-cx

Here I'm assigning LocalIp std::string. Is there any way to convert? 
When I'm using it, I get the following error

> cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'const wchar_t *' + windows phone runtime component

```
property String^ LocalIp;
LocalIp = ref new String(_aLNetworkAdapterInfo->_localIp.c_str());
std::string _localIp;
```

Answer (score 1):

For this conversion you can use `marshal_as`:

```
auto localIp = msclr::interop::marshal_as<String^>(_aLNetworkAdapterInfo->_localIp);
```

This requires:

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
```

Take a look at [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) for more details.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply . This code which you sent is work but , when trying to rebuild i'm getting the following error .                                     Error 14 error C1114: 'c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll' : WinRT does not support #using of a managed assembly (Requests\TransferFailRequest.cpp) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\vcclr.h 16 1 AnylyncRuntimeComponent . I searched over google for the above but no use .could please help me regarding this.

Comment: @Pallam oh sorry, looks like you're using C++/CX and not C++/CLI - I can't help you with this one as I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `std::wstring` if you want to interoperate with WinRT `Platform::String^`. If you really need a `std::string` then you can use `WideCharToMultiByte` for the conversion.